# Creating a save/load function with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a function that can save/load in XML format. The problem is that I am doing something wrong with the MainViewModel that leads to some errors. I done it this way and commented where I get the errors and which:

```
namespace Editor
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private double _x;
        private object _content;
        public object Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
            set
            {
                _content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Content));
            }
        }

        public double X
        {
            get { return _x; }
            set
            {
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(X));
            }
        }

        public ICommand BtnLoadCommand { get; }

        public ICommand BtnGemCommand { get; }

        public double Y { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Content = new Save_Load(); //the type or namespace could not be found are you missing an assembly 
            BtnLoadCommand = new RelayCommand(Load); //cannot convert from method group to action
            BtnGemCommand = new RelayCommand(Save); //cannot convert from method group to action
        }

        private void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog loadfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (loadfildialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }

        private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog gemfiledialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (gemfildialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting some pretty standard compile time errors here; there is no "Save_Load" method in the code, and your parameters to `RelayCommand` almost certainly don't match what it expects (an `Action<object>` usually). Do you have a more specific question about the errors?

Comment: BtnLoadCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Load); 
BtnGemCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Save);

Answer (score -1):

Try below

```
BtnLoadCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Load); 
BtnGemCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Save);
```

Comment: Hello :) It says: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Comment: I edited the answer after 1 more view :). This would work

Comment: This won't work either, the signatures won't match (you gave Action<object> and he is passing Action<object, EventArgs>). Your comment was closer (but needed an actual method invocation). If you are going to answer his question, please try to explain it in detail as just giving him the working code is doing no one any favors.